# Installing Flask fails. Error: No available formula with the name "flask"

Tags: python, flask, pip, virtualenv, homebrew

I use Mac and I am new to Flask. I first wanted to install `virtualenv` via command-line. This is the error I get:

```
$ brew install Flask 
Error: No available formula with the name "flask"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula... Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae... Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps... Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

When I tried to install Flask via pip, it gave me this error:

```
$ pip install Flask
/usr/local/bin/pip: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/bin/pip: line 1: `var freckle = require('freckle')'
```

I just wanted to start with Flask, I'm completely new to this framework.
I often get this error when I try to install a module of Python. I use Python 2.7.10.

Thanks in regard. (stop deleting this. I am a friendly person)

Comment: are you using virtualenv? did you activate it?

Comment: I tried to, but it gave me exactly the same error as above.. no formulae found.

Comment: try:rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core; brew update

Comment: Did you try this: `sudo pip install virtualenv`?

Comment: Ok, I did, then came: "Already up-to-date."

When I tried to install Flask again, it gives me the same error as before.

Comment: try : 1) brew tap --repair 2)brew update

Comment: I did, and the same error occures. But now it takes much longer until the error comes up.

Comment: yes, I did "brew tap --repair" first, and then "brew update". And then there came "Already up-to-date" again. And then the same error when I tried to install.
And I also tried `sudo pip install` before.. same error: `/usr/local/bin/pip: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token ('
/usr/local/bin/pip: line 1: var freckle = require('freckle')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the only thing that actually worked, was:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
pip3 install Flask
```

Thanks to everyone, who helped out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
brew update && brew install flask
```

The problem might be that the directory is not up to date. The above command should clear that. Cheers.

Comment: This didn't work. :-(
`Already up-to-date.
Error: No available formula with the name "flask" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.`

Comment: Flask is not a brew formula.

Comment: yes, it was just a desperate trial of me after `pip install Flask` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So, you already have virtualenv installed.

Now what you need to do is create and activate a virtualenv for your project.

First, go to your project folder and then do this:

```
virtualenv project_name
```

Activate it:

```
. project_name/bin/activate
```

And install flask:

```
pip install Flask
```

Hope it helps. Read more about it [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/installation/)

Comment: No, installing virtualenv gave me the same error: formular not found.
`Error: No available formula with the name "virtualenv" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly named formulae were found:
pyenv-virtualenv ✔                                     pyenv-virtualenvwrapper ✔
To install one of them, run (for example):
  brew install pyenv-virtualenv ✔
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
`

Comment: @LeaHontiveros you commented that it said `Already up-to-date` which is means that it is installed

Comment: yes, because `brew` is already up-to-date. (the command was: `brew update && ...`)
The comment on the very top was after @asmita gave me a command.
Sorry, it was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is caused by a npm package which exposes an executable with the name `pip`.
To install python packages using pip, run:

```
python -m pip install <package name>
```

In your case:

```
python -m pip install Flask
```