# Installing Pythonenv on VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, homebrew, pyenv

Currently I'm trying to use brew to install pyenv on my VSCode terminal, but anytime I do this command in my terminal:

`brew install pyenv`

I get this message:

`Error: No available formula or cask with the name "pyenv".`

Can someone please walk me through how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This is not the best platform for walk-through help for troubleshooting. Relevant IRC channels are a good place for that kind of help, and once you've collected enough information and have a concrete question, Stackoverflow comes in!

Comment: It's always worth doing a search on error messages you get. The first hit for your error is https://stackoverflow.com/q/44302437/2299939. Does that discussion contain any helpful information?

Comment: @Ratler The answers on that question won't help here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: No similarly named formulae found. Error: No available formula or cask with the name "python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66032996/error-no-similarly-named-formulae-found-error-no-available-formula-or-cask-wi)